Roots of $t+\frac{b}{a-b}t^{1-a}-\frac{a}{a-b}$
I am working on an optimisation problem in which I would like to know where the feasible set bifurcates from its convex hull. The feasible set is bounded by the positive axes and the parametric curve
$$y = (1-t)^b, \quad x=t^a$$
for $0<a<1<b$ and $0<x<1$.
My question is whether there is an analytical/explicit solution to the following equation, which I believe is satisfied by the point where the feasible set bifurcates from its convex hull.
$$ t+\frac{b}{a-b}t^{1-a}-\frac{a}{a-b} = 0$$
I know there are series solutions for trinomial equations, but I don't know how or if they apply, especially because the second power is a real number. I am not really interested in numerical or approximate solutions.

An equation usually contains an equals sign.

I'm assuming he means when the expression is equal to zero here.

Thank you, original post amended.

Mathematica doesn't give an answer, and when $a=\frac{1}{10}, b=\frac{3}{2}$ it gives an answer only in terms of the root of a particular degree-9 polynomial rather than in a closed form; so my guess would be "no".

Of course $x=1$ is a solution.  For values $a=1/7,b=3/2$, if we remove the $x=1$ solution, what remains has Galois group $S_6$, so is not solvable.

I would contend that $a=1/7, b = 3/2$ has a solution of approximately $x = 0.417$. By plotting the equation. More generally it appears there always exists a root in (0,1) for any parameters meeting the constraints.

There are derivations here. Did you maybe try to follow one and see if you could start finding the series solution?

Happy to see thé question reopened (I was first one asking for it). Now we can discuss for even better if you wish. Cheers

Sorry Tyma Gaidash, my mistake. I am interested in analytic solutions! OG post edited.

Did you try any of the possible solutions given in answers ? It is an interesting problem.

The comments helped me get a feel for the problem. But I have found a path which sidesteps the need to find $t$ explicitly.

Dear G-Shillcock I am looking for applications of a new math function that I have been working. If you wish we could discuss better.

One can simplify the equation:
$$t+\frac{b}{a-b}t^{1-a}-\frac{a}{a-b}=0\iff t^{1-a}+(c-1)t-c=0,c=\frac ab\\\implies t=\frac{c-t^{a-1}}{c-1}$$
Now apply Lagrange reversion and substitute $t^{1-a}=w$ since $t=\frac c{1-c}<0$ is a bad approximation for the positive roots:
$$w+(c-1)w^\frac1{1-a}-c=0\iff w=c-(c-1)w^\frac1{1-a}\\\implies t=c^\frac1{1-a}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-c)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dc^{n-1}}\big(c^\frac1{1-a}\big)’c^\frac n{1-a}$$
giving the factorial power $u^{(v)}$: $$\boxed{t^{1-a}+(c-1)t-c=0\implies t=c^\frac1{1-a}+\frac1{1-a}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-c)^n}{n!}c^\frac{an+1}{1-a}\left(\frac{n+a}{1-a}\right)^{(n-1)}}$$
shown here. The sum has a closed form in terms of Fox H/Wright function. For $a\in\Bbb Q$, they can simplify into the hypergeometric function

Nice answer (as usual, may I say ?). Would you mind to use your formula for the two examples and tell me how many terms you need to add to get the solution (say with six significant figures). I am just curious. Cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici Unfortunately, the series is not the best for roots $t>0.4$ or so, but it works well for smaller roots. Maybe another series can be found using the theorem for them. You can test it editing this code: NumberForm[ReplaceAll[{c->0.35,a->0.6}][c^(1/(1 - a)) + (1/(1 - a)) Sum[((1 - c)^n/n!) (c^((a n + 1)/(1 - a)) FactorialPower[(a + n)/(1 - a), n - 1]), {n, 1, 35}]],10] with $c=\frac ab$

This is a pitty. The solution is so elegant. Thanks  cheers

Assuming that we look for the first zero of function $$f(x)=x+\frac{b}{a-b}x^{1-a}-\frac{a}{a-b}$$ taking into account the conditions $(0<a<1<b)$,  the first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\sqrt[a]{\frac{(1-a)\, b}{b-a} } $$ Using series around this point, being optimistic, a first estimate is
$$x_0=x_*-\sqrt{-2\frac{f(x_*) }{f''(x_*) } }$$
What we can show (looking at the required contour plots) is that
$$f(x_0) < 0 \qquad f'(x_0)=0 \qquad f''(x_0) >0$$
Using this estimate, perform $\color{red}{\text{one single}}$ iteration of the Newton-like method of order $n$; the obtained $x_1$ is fully explicit even if messy.
Working the two cases given in comments :

$a=\frac 1{10}$ and $b=\frac 32$  give $x_*=0.695116$ and  $x_0=0.410996$ while the solution is $x=0.432936$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_1^{(n)}    & \text{method} \\
 2 & 0.431814 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 & 0.432898 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 & 0.432935 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 & 0.432936 & \text{no name} \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty &0.432936 & \text{solution} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$a=\frac 1{7}$ and $b=\frac 32$  give $x_*=0.684908$ and  $x_0=0.392973$ while the solution is $x=0.417350$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_1^{(n)}    & \text{method} \\
 2 & 0.4159667 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 & 0.4172993 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 & 0.4173479 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 & 0.4173500 & \text{no name} \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty &0.4173500 & \text{solution} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$



Figure : Graphical representation of the two cases above.
Edit
If you are concerned by computer efficiency, notice that, for $n \geq 2$
$$\frac{d^{n+1}f(x)} {dx^{n+1}} =-\frac{d^{n}f(x)} {dx^{n}}\,\times \, \frac{a+(n+2) } x$$  Remember that computing the fractional power of a number is very expensive (going to logarithms and then to exponentials).
Update
If you prefer, you can use power series reversion. Since we know all coefficients for the series expansion of $f(x)$ built around $x_0$, using the general formulation given by  Morse and Feshbach, we know all coefficients of the reversed series and then the solution. This is not numerical but strictly formal.
As a function of the order of the initial expansion, here are the results for the two worked examples
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_{(n)} \\
 1 & 0.431814 \\
 2 & 0.432844 \\
 3 & 0.432927 \\
 4 & 0.432935 \\
 5 & 0.432936 \\
 6 & 0.432936 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_{(n)} \\
 1 & 0.415967 \\
 2 & 0.417226 \\
 3 & 0.417336 \\
 4 & 0.417348 \\
 5 & 0.417350 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Starting from the other side, consider instead the function
$$g(x)=\frac{b-a} {x-1}\left( x+\frac{b}{a-b}x^{1-a}-\frac{a}{a-b}\right)$$
which is
$$g(x)=a (b-1)-b\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{1-a}{n+1}\,(x-1)^n$$
With this, we have all coefficients of the base series that is to say the explicit expression of all coefficients of its inverse using the method proposed by Morse and Feshbach in year $1953$ (have a look at formula $(11)$). So, even if the result is an infinite sum, it is totally formal.
The solutions will write as
$$x=1+2t+(1+a)\sum_{n=2}^\infty P_n(a) \, t^n\quad \text{where}\quad t=-\frac{b-1}{(1-a) b}$$ the first polynomials in $a$ being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(a) \\
 2 & \frac{4}{3} \\
 3 & \frac{2}{9} (5 a+2) \\
 4 & \frac{8}{135} \left(17 a^2+10 a+2\right) \\
 5 & \frac{2}{405} \left(193 a^3+129 a^2+48 a+4\right) \\
 6 & \frac{4}{2835} \left(655 a^4+448 a^3+249 a^2+28 a+4\right) \\
 7 & \frac{2 }{42525} \left(19349 a^5+12724 a^4+9983 a^3+908 a^2+484
   a-16\right)\\
 8 & \frac{16 }{127575}\left(7217 a^6+4350 a^5+4782 a^4+115 a^3+498 a^2-60 a+8\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Using only the above table, the solutions for the worked examples are
$\color{red}{0.4329364}24$ and $\color{red}{0.4173500}64$
Using twice more terms, they will be
$\color{red}{0.43293644970}70$ and
$\color{red}{0.41735003564}34$

Your equation
\begin{align}
t+\frac{b}{a-b} t^{1-a}- \frac{a}{a-b}=0
\end{align}
has exact solutions for
\begin{align}
a=\frac{1}{2}  \;,\; b \neq \frac{1}{2} \;,\;
t=\frac{1}{(2b-1)^2} 
\end{align}
For $a=\frac{1}{3}$ we need to solve the equation
$ b=\frac{1+t^{\frac{1}{3}}+t^{\frac{2}{3}}}{3 t^{\frac{2}{3}} }$
giving the solutions $t =\frac{2}{(2 - 9 b + 3\sqrt{3} \sqrt{b^2 (-1 + 4 b)})}  \;\; \forall \; b> 1$
It also works for $a=\frac{1}{5}$ for example for b=2 we get the solution  t which is one of the roots of $-1 - 46 t - 856 t^2 - 8146 t^3 + 59049 t^4$
One can find exact solutions using the Findinstance from Mathematica
For $a=\frac{1}{7}$ and $b=3$ we get the solution  t which is one of the roots of $-1 - 141 t - 8541 t^2 - 288541 t^3 - 5888541 t^4 - 
 73088541 t^5 + 1280000000 t^6$

For $a=1/2,1/3,1/4$ no problem

@Claude for $a=1/5$ also

As a third attempt, consider funtion $$h(x)=x^a\,\frac{b-a} {x-1}\left( x+\frac{b}{a-b}x^{1-a}-\frac{a}{a-b}\right)$$ which is
$$h(x)=\frac{b x \left(x^a-1\right)}{x-1}-a x^a$$ that is to say
$$h(x)=\left(\frac{b x_0
   \left(x_0^a-1\right)}{x_0-1}-a x_0^a\right)+x_0^{a-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n\,\left(\frac{x-x_0}{x_0}\right)^n$$ where
$$\alpha_n=x_0 (b-a)\, \binom{a}{n} \,\,
   _2F_1\left(1,n-a;n+1;\frac{x_0-1}{x_0}\right
   )+$$ $$(a+(b-a)x_0)\, \binom{a}{n+1} \,\,
   _2F_1\left(1,n-a+1;n+2;\frac{x_0-1}{x_0}\right)$$ and
$$x_0=\frac{(a-1)(b-2) } {(a+1) b-2a }$$
If one would prefer simpler formulae, using $x_0=1$
$$h(x)=a(b-1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg((b-a) \binom{a}{n}+b \binom{a}{n+1}\Bigg)\,(x-1)^n$$
For the worked examples, using the very first iterates of Newton method
$$x_0=\frac{9}{29} \implies x_1=0.424733\implies x_2=0.432902\implies x_3= 0.432936$$
$$x_0=\frac{3}{10} \implies x_1=0.4108513\implies x_2=0.417331\implies x_3= 0.417350$$

Why post 3 different answers?

@ТymaGaidash. I did prefer to make them separate since I use three different functions. But,in principle, I should agree agree with you. and I should ask the same question. Cheers :-)

Try the following condition:
When
$$ r \cdot \bigg(\frac{a-b}{b} \bigg) \cdot \bigg(\frac{a}{b} \bigg)^r < -1 \cdot  a^{(r+1)}  $$
with $r= \frac{a}{1-a}$ you will have $t^{1-a} $ in complex plane.
In the equality you will have a double real solution (for $t$) analytically described
$ t^{1-a} = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{r+1}{r}$
For the case $a=1/10, b=3/2$ one has $t = 0.432936449708496 \space  or \space t= 0.999999999999998$
the critical $t_{Thr} = 0.637298718948650$.
For the case $a=1/10, b=3/2$ one has $t = 0.432936449708496 \space  or \space t= 0.999999999999998$
the critical $t_{Thr} = 0.637298718948650$.
